# SQL Overlap Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table that has two columns X1 and X2, where X1 is always less than X2. Each row makes up some range (X1, X2). It is possible that several rows have their X1/X2 ranges overlap to make some larger range (X1n, X2m).

Is there a way to query using standard SQL to find all of these ranges?

For example, the table might look like:

```
|x1         |x2       |
-----------------------
|1          |3        |
|2          |4        |
|3          |5        |
|7          |9        |
|8          |27       |
|100        |105      |
-----------------------
```

The expected output would be:

```
((1, 5), (7, 27), (100, 105))
```

I appreciate any help our points in the right direction.

I am using sqlite `3.11.0`.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?  This is possible with window functions and much harder without.

Comment: Can you include some example rows (in a format easily imported to a table, **not** as an image or whatever) and desired results based on that data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm using sqlite3, I've added that info to the question.

Comment: @PhillipMartin . . . Your version is too old to be really useful, alas.  You want 3.26 or newer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I am not married to that version. Is this simple with 3.26 or newer?

Comment: @PhillipMartin . . . Window functions are supported in 3.26, which makes this simpler (but not simple) to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
t1.x1  AS Start,
MIN(t2.x2) AS End
FROM test t1 
INNER JOIN test t2 ON t1.x1 <= t2.x2
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t3 
                     WHERE t2.x2 >= t3.x1 AND t2.x2 < t3.x2) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t4 
                 WHERE t1.x1 > t4.x1 AND t1.x1 <= t4.x2) 
GROUP BY t1.x1
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csGQzDX7Tbo9UeTf7ATDd/0)

Comment: I should add that `x1n` and `x2m` are not necessarily known, it just represents what hypothetically might be the minimum and maximum of a range containing several x1/x2 ranges.